# Change of basis matrix for an operator

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, operator-theory

Suppose I have two operators,  $D \equiv \frac{d}{dt}$ and $D^2 \equiv \frac{d^2}{dt^2}$, represented in matrix form by two different bases $\mathbf{e} = \left \{\cos (wt), \sin (wt) \right \}$ and $\mathbf{e'} = \left \{e^{iwt}, e^{-iwt} \right \}$.

For $\mathbf{e}$:

$$D_{\mathbf{e}} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0  &w \\ -w & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \ \  D_{\mathbf{e}}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} -w^2  &0 \\ 0 & -w^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

For $\mathbf{e'}$:

$$D_{\mathbf{e'}} =  \begin{pmatrix} iw  &0 \\ 0 & -iw \end{pmatrix}, \ \  D_{\mathbf{e'}}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} -w^2  &0 \\ 0 & -w^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

How do I proceed if I wanted to find the transformation matrix between the bases $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{e'}$?

In my old linear algebra textbook there's a tutorial of how to do it for vectors (column matrices) but I got confused when trying to do it with operators (square matrices).

Answer (score 1):

The basis vectors are not column matrices (as you noted in your question) but they are not square matrices either.  They are the functions in the two bases, that is, $\cos wt$ etc.  The transformation matrix from $\def\b#1{{\bf#1}}\b e'$ to $\b e$ has columns which are the functions in $\b e'$, expressed as coordinate vectors with respect to $\b e$.  Since the first vector (i.e., function) in $\b e'$ can be written
$$e^{iwt}=\cos wt+i\sin wt\ ,$$
the matrix is
$$\pmatrix{1&?\cr i&?\cr}$$
and I'm sure you can do the rest for yourself.

Comment: Is it really that simple? I don't believe it (with all due respect).

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood the question, it is really that simple.  Transformation matrices between bases depend only on the bases and have nothing to do with any particular operator.